# apt-get mass install packages from a file?

Tags: apt

I have a text file with lots of package names.

```
package1
package2

# comment
# installing package3 because it was needed for...
package 3

package 4
```

How can I mass install all packages inside the text file without removing the comments?

Comment: This solution allows you to use comments: https://www.monolune.com/installing-apt-packages-from-a-requirements-file/

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Something along these lines ought to do the trick.

```
apt-get install $(grep -vE "^\s*#" filename  | tr "\n" " ")
```

The $(something) construction runs the *something* command, inserting its output in the command line.

The grep command will exclude any line beginning with a #, optionally allowing for whitespace before it. Then the tr command replaces newlines with spaces.

Comment: `tr` will fail with multi-byte end-of-line sequences (think `\r\n`), why don't you use `xargs`?

Comment: You can also ignore trailing comments ```apt-get install $(grep -vE "^\s*#" Aptfile | sed -e 's/#.*//'  | tr "\n" " ")```

Comment: Just wondering, how difficult would it be to create a "dummy package", which is empty except for metadata. I know that the `depends` argument in the metadata is used by apt / apt-get commands as input, just as if you were to type `sudo apt install <argument>`. Seems like it would be a great solution to this issue. I would post myself, but I am not sure about the specifics. maybe someone a bit more experienced at package creation / handling could pick up the torch here?

Comment: Can this done one by one?

Answer (score 20):

The following command is a (slight) improvement over the alternative because `sudo apt-get install` is not executed when the package list is empty.

```
xargs -a <(awk '! /^ *(#|$)/' "$packagelist") -r -- sudo apt-get install
```

Note that the `-a` option reads items directly from a file instead of standard input. We don't want to pipe a file into `xargs` because stdin must remain unchanged for use by `apt-get`.

Comment: `xargs` is the right way to do this. Trick with `<()` is neat.

Comment: That's indeed the better solution because `xargs` makes sure `ARG_MAX ` is not reached.

Comment: It has to be `xargs -a $(awk '/^\s*[^#]/' "$packagelist") -r -- sudo apt-get -y install`, not "`<(`" but "`$(`" and the option `-y` for apt-get would be a good idea.

Comment: Process substitution redirects the output of `awk` into a file descriptor for `xargs -a` to read from. So you definitely want `<(` and not `$(`. Just try it and you'll see what I mean. If the command is to be running unattended and you already know exactly what's going to be installed then sure, they `-y` flag is a good idea.

Comment: Would it be still run if one of the packages in the list crashes to be installed?

Answer (score 8):

Given a package list file `package.list`, try:

```
sudo apt-get install $(awk '{print $1}' package.list)
```

Comment: How does it help with `#`?

Comment: ```zsh: parse error near `}
zsh: parse error near $(awk '{print $1'} p...'
```

Comment: This is a good solution, but slightly incorrect. The second `'` character is slightly misplaced. The correct syntax is:

`sudo apt-get install $(awk '{print $1}' package.list)`

Answer (score 3):

I use this simple solution:

```
grep -vE '^#' file.txt | xargs sudo apt install -y
```

`grep` finds all lines that don't start with a `#` and gives them as arguments to `sudo apt install`.

Answer (score 2):

Well, here's my solution to install a list of packages I have for fresh install:

```
sudo apt install -y $(grep -o ^[^#][[:alnum:].-]* "filename")
```

In a `bash` function :

```
aptif () {
    sudo apt install -y $(grep -o ^[^#][[:alnum:].-]* "$1")
}
```

`grep` explanation :

- `-o` keep only the part of line that matches the expression
- `^[^#]` anything that does not start with a `#`
- `[[:alnum].-]*` a sequence of letters, numbers, `.` and `-`

Comment: I needed to add a `.` after `[:alnum:]` in order to support package names with a `.`.

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by the accepted answer here and [this answer on removing comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/157607/85161):

```
apt-get install $(grep -o '^[^#]*' filename)
```